# Are there any motifs or symbols related to imperialism in Animal Farm?

Tags: george-orwell, animal-farm

In my centennial edition of *Animal Farm* by George Orwell, his bio states that he joined the Burmese Indian Imperial Police stating,

> In order to hate imperialism, you have got to be part of it.

In *Animal Farm*, George Orwell satirizes the Russian Revolution, which most definitely involved imperialist elements. Is imperialism satirized in *Animal Farm*? If so, how is it satirized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Orwell doesn't satirize imperialism, but he seems to say it doesn't work well.  He acknowledges it's flaws, primarily the fact that the people aren't too happy.

At the start of the book, Mr. Jones is a successful farmer. His animals aren't being mistreated, though they are treated as animals and thus not equal to humans. They are mostly content (not really happy though), but they *jump* at the chance to had a 'democratic' group (nation? farmyard? barnyard?) of animals.

So in Orwell's mind, imperialism may not be the best system, but it's certainly productive. However, it's vulnerable to revolutions such as the pig's revolution.

Also note that Orwell appears to be satirizing England/the US and Germany with Mr. Pilkington and Frederick, not really their political systems specifically.